# exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17a1d170'

Tags: ios

I have the above error in my code but I don't know how to solve that please help me for to solve that.

I have give that code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictNewHour = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    if (_datedetailsArray.count > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < _datedetailsArray.count; i++){
            if ([[_datedetailsArray[i] valueForKey:@"totalhours"] isEqualToString:@"4"]) -----> **In this line I have that error**{
                NSString *new4Hour = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[_datedetailsArray[i] valueForKey:@"totalhours"],fourOnly];
                [dictNewHour setObject:new4Hour forKey:@"totalhours"];
                [fourHoursArray addObject:dictNewHour];
                NSLog(@"fourHoursArray is:%@",fourHoursArray);
                NSLog(@"fourHoursArray count is:%lu",(unsigned long)fourHoursArray.count);

                append4String = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %lu %@", hr4String, (unsigned long)fourHoursArray.count, daysString];

                NSLog(@"append4String is:%@",append4String);
            }
```

Comment: The error says that your `[[_datedetailsArray[i] valueForKey:@"totalhours"]` object it is not a `NSString` instance it is a `NSArray` check your data

Comment: Thanks for your response@iSashok

Answer (score 0):

"isEqualToString" is NSString class method and you are accessing this method with NSArray object So Please check the data